# opencv :: Multiple unwanted window with Garbage name

Tags: c++, opencv

i am using opencv to capture video from webcam and display it in namedWindow.

```
cv::Mat rawImage;
cv::VideoCapture captureDevice;
captureDevice.open(0);
cv::namedWindow("webcam", 1);
bool running = true;
while(running)
{
    captureDevice >> rawImage;
    if(!rawImage.data)
    {
        continue;
    }
    cv::imshow("webcam", rawImage);
    char ch = cv::waitKey(33);
    if(ch == 'e')
    running = false;
}
```

initially code runs fine but after random (5 sec approx) period older named window freezes and new window with some garbage name pops up and start showing webcam images. this continues to happen and i am getting multiple unwanted named window. What is the reason for popping up for those unwanted windows?

Comment: I've had this once, but I can't remember what was causing it. Are you running Linux? Have you tried changing the waitKey value? Does it matter wich name you choose for the window?

Comment: I m using window 7. I tried changing wait key value as well as name but both doesn't matter. Sometimes title of named window appear along with some garbage value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried the solution described here?

http://www.ridgesolutions.ie/index.php/2013/09/26/opencv-display-window-title-corrupted-and-multiple-windows-show/

They also indicate that they don't understand why, but that it was manually fixed by adding preprocessor definition `_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL=0` to VS2012

Comment: `#define _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL 0`

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue with opencv 2410 and visual studio 2013 , window 7 64 bit.
Resolved when I **linked debug libraries** for debug configuration.

e.g. opencv_highgui2410**d**.lib

Comment: is this the full answer?

Answer (score 0):

No `waitkey()` is existed in OpenCV, only `waitKey()` (maybe you have a typo here). Anyway, try to change

```
char ch = cv::waitkey(33);
```

to

```
char ch = cv::waitKey(33);
```

and test again. I have tested it on my PC (under VS2010), it worked fine.

Comment: Thanks! it was a typo.. fixed it in question but the problem is still persist.