# opencv after install characters look awkward

Tags: opencv

Good day
I installed VS2013 on windows 8.1 x64 
I was trying to install opencv and i had alot of problems the final 
error 
LNK1112: module machine type 'X86' conflicts with target machine type 'x64' 
I could solve all problems
but now I used code for capture stream from USB webcam
the image frame name look wrong name and there is window for each frame 
that should only one window to display frame stream not window for each frame
why that is happening
this is image for the result and i will post the code too 
[image]

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<opencv\cv.h>
#include<opencv\highgui.h>
using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    Mat image;
    VideoCapture cap;
    cap.open(0);
    namedWindow("N", 1);
    while (1)
    {
        cap>>image;
        imshow("N", image);
        waitKey(33);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

thank you in advance.

Comment: I did install opencv and there was a lot of things but i solved most but this error is really awkward ... am using windows 8.1 x64 and but i used opencv 32 bit and before i used the 64 bit i thought this was because of system type but i had same problems >>> any suggestions

Comment: ^ any modern x64 CPU/OS is perfectly capable of running 32 bit programs.

Comment: try flipping the project's charset from/to unicode?

Comment: did what you told me but i have the same problem and you might like to take a look at those warnings   C:\Program Files\Microsoft LifeCam\DriverComponents\ViperRT.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.

Comment: i have bunch of this pdb errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem solved from this link they had similar

[opencv :: Multiple unwanted window with Garbage name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20854682/opencv-multiple-unwanted-window-with-garbage-name)

thanks for you all :) now am having one frame and perfect resolution