cv.namedWindow title is not shown correctly(shows garbage) with Qt on Ubuntu

import cv2 as cv 
img_c = cv.imread('candy.jpg', cv.IMREAD_COLOR)
cv.namedWindow('Image', cv.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv.resizeWindow('Image', (600, 300))
cv.imshow('Image', img_c)
cv.setWindowTitle('Image', 'MyCandy img_c')
cv.waitKey(0)

Above code shows title correctly on Ubuntu 24.04 with opencv 4.9.0 and python 3.11.8.
However in Ubuntu 22.04(same cv and py), the title is not shown correctly as shown in figure. Anyone knows what I am missing?
Any comment will be appreciated...
I'm using anaconda.
I have installed opencv using "conda install -c conda-forge opencv".
Using cv.imshow() without namedWindow() has same problem.

Your code is working. What is your OS system?

this might be Qt, or GTK. print(cv.getBuildInformation()) and find the GUI section to determine this.

In Windows this typically occurs when you mix debug and release build/libs. Maybe a similar problem in linux (sone kind of heap corruption)?

This is such a windows/vc case: https://stackoverflow.com/q/20854682/2393191 but there is at least one comment that had a similar problem in Linux.

Thanks everyone!
Ubuntu 22.04 on VirtualBox 7.0.18.
Build Information: (some output you may see)
General configuration for OpenCV 4.9.0
Version control:               5fba48a-dirty
Extra modules:
OpenCV modules:
GUI:                           QT6
QT:                          YES (ver 6.7.0 )
QT OpenGL support:         NO

potential bug, related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78546581/unable-to-read-image-opencv-c
