Unable to read image OpenCV c++
I'm stuck with OpenCV image read function because somehow he can't read an image. Yes the path is correct and the image exist. I watched some tutorial on Youtube to display an image to find the problem without success. I also try to debug to check if my path was wrong but it seem to work perfectly fine so i'm kinda lost.

Similar issue:
https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/24632
https://forum.opencv.org/t/opencv-4-7-c-17-windows-10-imread-warn-cutoff-empty-return/12089
My issue:

[ WARN:0@0.382] global loadsave.cpp:248 cv::findDecoder imread_(''):
can't open/read file: check file path/integrity OpenCV Exception:
OpenCV(4.9.0)
C:\GHA-OCV-1_work\ci-gha-workflow\ci-gha-workflow\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp:449:
error: (-215:Assertion failed) !winname.empty() in function
'cv::namedWindow'

Console app
C++ 17 X64 unicode
Compiler: VS 2022
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <Windows.h>

int main()
{
    try {
        cv::Mat img = cv::imread("C:\\Users\\S06\\Downloads\\panneau.jpg", cv::IMREAD_COLOR);
        cv::namedWindow("Image", cv::WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
        cv::imshow("Image", img);
        cv::waitKey(0);
    }
    catch (const cv::Exception& e) {
        std::cerr << "OpenCV Exception: " << e.what() << std::endl;
        system("pause");
        return -1;
    } catch (const std::exception& e) {
        std::cerr << "Standard Exception: " << e.what() << std::endl;
        system("pause");
        return -1;
    } catch (...) {
        std::cerr << "Unknown Exception" << std::endl;
        system("pause");
        return -1;
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}


In both cases it seems to be complaining about empty strings, while the parameters are clearly not empty.... You mention "unicode" -- what do you mean by that? How exactly are you trying to build this?

Configuration properties > Character set = "Use unicode char set"

[Edit] your question and add it there.

I would put those string literals (the file name and window name) into explicit std::string variables, see if it recurs. If it does, step through it in a debugger and observe the in-memory representation of the strings. Maybe even use the debug build of OpenCV in debugging mode to step inside the functions.

I saw similar issues recently in another question, where strings somehow fail to get translated into whatever OpenCV wants. this might be an issue with a recent release of OpenCV, or the compiler version, or build options. you talked about "unicode" strings... OpenCV might not like that. -- in the other question, we only saw an issue with imread() but now you show that namedWindow also appears to have the same issue.

potential bug, related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78544358/cv-namedwindow-title-is-not-shown-correctlyshows-garbage-with-qt-on-ubuntu

Multi bytes do the same, may be related to a lasted version of OpenCV. It's the first time i use it so i don't know

related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78922334/videowriter-not-opening-using-opencv-with-c
