VideoWriter not opening using OpenCV with C++
I am trying to use VideoWriter OpenCV in C++ but it does not open and prints an error in the console. I am on a Windows 10 machine using Visual Studio.
Here is the code I use:
#include <iostream> // for standard I/O
#include <string>   // for strings
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"


using namespace std;
using namespace cv;


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    VideoWriter outputVideo1;
    outputVideo1.open("testing.avi", VideoWriter::fourcc('M', 'J', 'P', 'G'), 10, Size(1936, 1216), false);
    if (!outputVideo1.isOpened())
    {
        cout << "failed opening" << endl;
    }
   
}

The error I got:

error: (-215:Assertion failed) !filename_pattern.empty() in function 'cv::CvVideoWriter_Images::open'

The things I've tried:
I have tried with different file locations names and extension as well as changing to different fourcc but its no working at all.
I also tried downloading the source code from the tutorial here:
https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d7/d9e/tutorial_video_write.html but when I ran it threw the same error.
I tried using open as done in: OpenCV VideoWriter does not open and got the error:

OpenCV(4.9.0) C:\GHA-OCV-1_work\ci-gha-workflow\ci-gha-workflow\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap_images.cpp:216: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !filename.empty() in function 'cv::icvExtractPattern' '

If it is of interest the videowriter in python works without a problem. As I am quite new to C++ it is possible that I am missing something very obvious, any help is appreciated!
Edit:
After enabling logging I notice that these to fail:

cv::impl::getPluginCandidates Found 2 plugin(s) for GSTREAMER
\OpenCV\build\x64\vc16\bin\opencv_videoio_gstreamer4100_64.dll => FAILED


cv::plugin::impl::DynamicLib::libraryLoad load C:\OpenCV\build\x64\vc16\bin\opencv_videoio_intel_mfx4100_64.dll => FAILED

But this one succeeded so I do not think that is the problem:

cv::plugin::impl::DynamicLib::libraryLoad load C:\OpenCV\build\x64\vc16\bin\opencv_videoio_msmf4100_64.dll => OK

Then it continues before raising an exceptionafter this:

cv::impl::PluginBackend::initWriterAPI Video I/O: plugin is ready to >use 'Microsoft Media Foundation OpenCV Video I/O plugin'


[ WARN:0@0.011] global cap.cpp:645 cv::VideoWriter::open >VIDEOIO(CV_IMAGES): raised OpenCV exception:


430: error: >(-215:Assertion failed) !filename_pattern.empty() in function >'cv::CvVideoWriter_Images::open'

Nothing of these seems to indicate a clear source of error...
FYI, if these logs are not relevant to the question I will remove this edit later on.

I think the CV exception is in this case misleading. The problem probably is in the video codecs support that your version of OpenCV offers. And that depends on how it was compiled on your machine. Unfortunately I couldn't find any entry in the docs that explains what are the filename patterns and fourcc codes requirements with respect to the supported codecs.

You can enable OpenCV debug prints by setting this env var export OPENCV_LOG_LEVEL=DEBUG. Then run your exec again and you might see which video plugins/codecs are missing.

you gotthe same issue with this codec type for example ? 'X', 'V', 'I', 'D'  also it could be help us to understand to see builg info if you send     cout << getBuildInformation() << endl; FFMPEG may not be exist in build config

@pptaszni So I enable logging, what I identified as important from the logs are in a new edit it the question. I didnt know how exactly change the env var so I used utils::logging::setLogLevel(cv::utils::logging::LOG_LEVEL_VERBOSE). Hope that gives a similar result. Thanks for the help!

@Yunus Yeah tried with different codecs it does not help both XVID and MPEG did not change anything. According to the logs FFMPEG seems to be loading just fine. I tried adding  cout << getBuildInformation() << endl; to the code but just ended up with an assertion error, maybe I did someting wrong. Appreciate the help!

the problem is not in the codec support. MJPEG and .avi are always supported because those are built in. -- this error suggests that the file path is empty. that has been an issue on Windows in the previous months. it's related to string literals and strings. the issue shows up as strings being "empty" that could not possibly be empty (because a string literal was given etc). I'm sure that's the problem. upgrade the library and try again. browse this, it's got issues linked: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78546581/unable-to-read-image-opencv-c

Just to be 100% clear you are using Visual Studio Community 2015 to 2022 with Microsoft's compiler msvc and not MinGW or g++.

OP could confirm (100%) but I think that's a good bet (99%). judging by the messages coming from the library, those look like official builds, done on github CI. they won't be mingw. -- such behavior had been an issue when opencv 4.9 was current. IDK the results of the bug investigations.

@drescherjm yeah its VSC 2022 with Microsoft's compiler

@ChristophRackwitz I redid everything on a windows 11 machine (the old was windows 10) and the problem persists. All the dlls seems to load correct, FFMPG, MSMF etc. So I am very confused, both have upgraded to the latest version of OpenCv now. To make sure I imported OpenCv as described here beneath the local method https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/dd/d6e/tutorial_windows_visual_studio_opencv.html , is there something during that process that could cause this?

weird. to confirm: you switched to a different host (Win11 even), you obtained official builds of OpenCV v4.10 for Windows, and you've built some test code that links against that library, and the "empty string" phenomenon still appears? fascinating. I'm not currently set up to try to replicate your situation. you ought to submit an issue to OpenCV's github, or find an appropriate existing one and add your voice. please mention that tutorial from the docs. it was probably not touched in ages and might need checking. looks fine though.

@ChristophRackwitz yes correct.
Ok I will submit an issue to the github then, I just hope I am not missing something obvious here. Thanks for the help!
